# Confusing webpack rule after `au new` using Aurelia CLI

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, aurelia

I'm trying to understand what magic happens that violates my understanding of webpack.

**To reproduce:**

1. `au new -u -s http2,dotnet-core,typescript,htmlmin-min,vscode,scaffold-navigation.
2. Open `webpack.config.js`
3. Review the module rules:

Notice this rule:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/i,
    issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
    // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
    // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
    use: cssRules
}
```

`cssRules` is defined as:

```
const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
];
```

All of that seems to mean that html files which `<require>` a css file will only utilize `css-loader`. And based on my understanding, `css-loader` doesn't inject the CSS into the page at all. At minimum, `style-loader` would be required to inject the CSS into the html file.

And yet, when I `<require>` a CSS file, it works exactly as expected.

Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I just stumbled across the answer to my own question. Maybe this will help someone else...

From https://github.com/jods4/aurelia-webpack-build/wiki/CSS-doesn't-load:

> With an Aurelia  in the view. In this case, Aurelia already provides the function to insert the CSS in DOM and expects just CSS code. You need only css-loader.